# python отправка через telegram-send

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код

```
import telegram_send
import random

phrases = ['some text']
finalP = random.choice(phrases)
telegram_send.send(messages=finalP)
```

Если сделать

```
finalP = random.choice(phrases)
print(finalP)
```

То в консоль падает рандомная фраза как и должно быть, но если исполняется последняя строка

```
telegram_send.send(messages=finalP)
```

То в телегу прилетает сообщения вида

[image: не так надо жеж(]

помогите новичку разобраться с отправкой полного сообщения

Спасибо!

Comment: `telegram_send.send(messages=[finalP])` ?

Comment: @strawdog сэр, это действительно работает, объясните новичку плиз почему так?

Comment: судя по ошибке, telegram_send.send в качестве параметра messages принимает список. если вы даете ему одиночную строку, то он ее интерпретирует как список и разбивает на буквы. поэтому одиночную строку нужно саму обернуть в список ([]), чтобы все работало как задумано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю @strawdog за помощь
Нужно было строку:
`telegram_send.send(messages=finalP)`
заменить на:
`telegram_send.send(messages=[finalP])`
вот правильный способ, нужно было добавить `[]`, обернуть в список, спасибо за пояснение @strawdog

Comment: Ответ ещё улучшите только, пожалуйста. Код выделите, пояснения скопируйте из комментариев.